# Time series data for issues listed on the (now defunct) GLBSE

Tags: exchanges, raw-data, glbse

I would like to get the following data for every issue ever listed on GLBSE:

1. Time series of closing prices since IPO to de-listing (or closing of GLBSE),
2. Date and quantity of initial and secondary offerings, and
3. Dividend history.

The motivation behind this is constructing a total return index for the GLBSE.

How can I get these data?

Comment: I wouldn't doubt there are traders who scraped all the data you are looking for.  A bounty offer might be the incentive to get you access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forum user captured the transaction and dividend history from the @GLBSE Twitter feed which can be used to determine daily pricing and dividends.  This is from v2 (April, 2012).

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=117491.0